# Why Spring boot Filter init function execute in different order pack as jar and war package

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, init

I run the Spring boot in the different way , jar and war package to run the code.

I need to run some code in the filter init method,  I run with jar ,it work.
However I run with war, it's order not right.

I want to know why and how to run in war get the result like run with jar way.

so , I write some code like these, and run in the different way , found it has different result.

SpringBootWebApplication.java

```java
@ComponentScan(value = "com", excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class))
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean hrFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<TestFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(new TestFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setName("testFiter");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    }

}
```

TestBean.java

```java
@Component
public class TestBean {
    public static String aaa = "nothing";

    public TestBean() {
        System.out.println(aaa);
    }
}
```

TestFilter.java

```java
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        TestBean.aaa = "good thing";
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {
        System.out.println("filter dofilter");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("filter destory");
    }
}
```

when I run with jar,I get the result:
good thing

when I run with war,I get the result:
nothing

I want to run with war, get the result:
good thing

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to use `@Order` annotation that can specify the order of running filters (but can be applied not only to filters)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html

Comment: the order is right, Filter init method not right(when I use the war, it run after TestBean.java instance).